# return a list of unmatched records between queries

Tags: sql-server

I apologize if this has been asked already I couldn't find anything that was quite what I wanted ->
Is there a way to return a list of records that do match two queries for example

```
ID  |  Name  | Color
1      crayon  blue
2      marker  red
3      paint   green

"Select Id, Name, color from TableA" =

ID  |  Name  | Color
1      crayon  blue
2      marker  red
3      paint   green

"Select Id, Name, color from TableA where color = 'blue'" = 

ID  |  Name  | Color
1      crayon  blue
```

I was hoping there was some functionality that would take the two queries above and provide a result set like:

```
ID  |  Name  | Color
2      marker  red
3      paint   green
```

Being the records of the two queries that do not equal. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just do `where color <> 'blue'` ?

Comment: because the queries will be formed dynamically so I won't know what the queries are at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
<query 1 here>
EXCEPT
<query 2 here>
```

Of course, use of EXCEPT assumes that:

- The number and the order of the columns must be the same in both
  queries.
- The data types must be compatible.

Answer (score 4):

I am going to assume that your queries are really more complicated and this is just an example.  One way is by using `left join`:

```
with q1 as (<query1 here>),
     q2 as (<query2 here>)
select q1.*
from q1 left join
     q2
     on q1.id = q2.id
where q2.id is null;
```

This assumes the match is on `id`.  If there are more column that need to be the same, add them to the `on` clause.

Comment: brilliant. This is so obvious now that my pride is injured. Thanks for the tip. Yes my tables are a bit more complicated haha :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query to get your desired result set:

```
Select Id, Name, color from TableA
EXCEPT
Select Id, Name, color from TableA where color = 'blue'
```